# override a weak function A with a function B

Tags: c, ld, weak-linking

For an embedded device, I have file containing an array with function pointers storing interrupt handlers, define like that (I can't modify it):

```
typedef void (*const ISRFunction)(void);

__attribute__((weak)) void ISR0(void){ for(;;); }
__attribute__((weak)) void ISR1(void){ for(;;); }
...
__attribute__((weak)) void ISR78(void){ for(;;); }
...

ISRFunction __vector_table[0x79] = 
{
    (ISRFunction)&ISR0,
    (ISRFunction)&ISR1,
    ...
    (ISRFunction)&ISR78,
    ...
}
```

I have a second file which defines some functions, which I can't modify. This file is like:

```
void blinkLed(void)
{ ... }
```

Finally, I have a main source file, with `main` function and configuration of device. On interrupt 78, I would like to blink led. So I write a strong function `ISR78` like that:

```
void ISR78(void)
{
    blinkLed();
}
```

I wondered if there was a solution to override weak function `ISR78` directly by `blinkLed`, *ie* storing address of `blinkLed` inside `__vector_table` without modifying it or rename function?

---

EDIT:

I actually use GNU gcc 4.9.3 and associated linker (GNU ld 2.24.0). I can modify `main.c` and Makefile associated to project.

Comment: Some compilers (don't know about yours) support symbol aliases, which might be something to look into.

Comment: Also, you should be very specific about the function types: `void func(void)` (no arguments) and `void func()` (unspecfied number of arguments) are different types. Use `void` always for functions without arguments to avoid problems.

Comment: @user694733 thanks for advice, I will take care about it

Comment: Probably I'm not the global vision of the problem, but `weak` is designed to allow to "override" function, isn't it? So you can define/implement your _same_name_function_ to override the `weak` one.

Comment: @LPs I have already do that. I override the `weak` function with a _same_name_function_ use as a wrapper to function doing real job. I wonder a method to directly override `weak` function with function doing real job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see to achieve what you want to do is to patch the symbol table of the object file containing the `blink` symbol with the `ISR78` symbol.

> objcopy [...] --redefine-sym blink=ISR78

should do that. The linker should then automatically insert the address of the former `blink` into the vector table. Obviously, your `blink` symbol is gone after that and shouldn't be called from other places.

I would, however, consider this a hack.

In case `_vector_table` is globally accessible and in writable memory (not assumed, that's probably too simple...), you could simply patch it from your own code by

```
_vector_table [0x78] = blink;
```

at runtime.

Comment: I will take a look at this method. I prefer a method with `__attribute__` or any specific or generic C code or with linker (linker option or linker script), but it's already a first method. I agree with you considering this as a hack. Also, it can be dangerous if `blink` is use in another place (but because it manages an ISR, it shouldn't be call else where)

Comment: @Garf365 maybe you could use `ld`'s `--defsym` command with an argument like `ISR78=blink` (or is it the other way round?) - I have, however, never tried this myself and don't really know what other implications this might have or whether it will work at all.

Comment: Finally, it's not the answer I wanted, but it seams to be the only possible answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Garf365 Have you tried my last proposal? It looked promising to me.

Comment: I didn't try your last proposal because `__vector_table` is in an read only memory... but thank, I will remember it if you move __vector_table into RAM

Comment: @Garf365 Actually, with "last proposal" I meant using `ld --defsym ISR78=blink`

Comment: Actually it works really fine, it's just not what I did expect.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: you have a working solution already, which appears to be the solution explicitly supported and encouraged by using weak symbols in the first place. What improvement do you expect from a different solution?

---

Linker symbols are looked up by name, so the only alternatives to using the expected name are:

1. tofro's suggestion to modify the link step directly
2. modify the function pointer table yourself

The whole point of making ISR78 a weak symbol in the first place is to allow exactly the override (by symbol name) you've already used.

I can't see any way modifying the interrupt vector table is *better* than just using the expected function name directly, even if it's possible.

Comment: I can understand the OP wants to remove that one indirection (which would typically evaluate to one single branch instruction) - There are problems where every cycle counts.

Comment: _Which_ one indirection? You're calling through a table, and the linker will fix up the table - including choosing between the weak and other symbols - at link time. There is _no impact_ at function call time whichever of these you choose (unless you use dynamic linking and there's a trampoline function, at least).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__asm("symbolname")` to do this.  This lets you change the name of the symbol used in the object file to be a specific string.  Both gcc and clang support this.

Example:

```c
void blinkLed(void) __asm("ISR78");  // Can only be used on a prototype
void blinkLed(void)
{ ... }
```

In your code, everything can use the name `blinkLed`.  But in the object file the name will be `ISR78` and it will override the weak version and be used as the interrupt vector.

This also works as a way to avoid C++ name mangling, even when you can't use `extern "C"`.

```cpp
template <int id>
struct Timer {
   static void blinkled();
};

template <> Timer<1>::blinkled() __asm("ISR71");
template <> Timer<2>::blinkled() __asm("ISR72");
```

Above we have a class template with an ISR, blinkled(), as a static method.  Then we define two specializations of that ISR for two different timers, and give each correct name for the interrupt vector it is on.

Comment: Really interesting solution, Badly, I can't modify header/source containing `blinkLed` so can't change prototype, but I will take this way to another project ! specially to manage with c++name mangling.

Comment: You can still use it.  One can write the prototype of a function multiple times.  It's not an error unless they conflict.  The `__asm()` in the prototype is additive.  Putting it in on *a* prototype changes the name.  Omitting it on another doesn't undo the name change.  So you can add it your own header and then include that one in the source that defines and it doesn't conflict with the prototype in the existing header.

Comment: Keep in mind that ISRs are special functions.  Usually one needs to use something like `__attribute__((interrupt))` or `__attribute__((signal))` when declaring them to get special code generated.  A normal function can't directly be an ISR.